# How can I convert GMT Date with php

Tags: php, date, datetime, gmt

I want to convert a date as below using php.

```
Mon Jun 17 2013 14:00:00 GMT 0300 (EEST)
```

When I run `date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("Mon Jun 17 2013 14:00:00 GMT 0300 (EEST)"))` the engine just generates `0300-06-17 15:56:56`. If I update the code like `date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("Mon Jun 17 2013 14:00:00 GMT"))` it generates `2013-06-17 17:00:00`. I have tried again and again but could not solve this issue. How Can I convert dates like this?

Answer (score 1):

try to set the time zone and try

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set your timezone like `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles')` and try using `gmdate()`.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php

If you are trying to convert GMT to your timezone then you should convert both to a UNIX timestamp and do the math.

See:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-timestamp-get.php

Comment: I set my date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Istanbul'). And run gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("Mon Jun 17 2013 14:00:00 GMT 0300 (EEST)")). But nothing changes. The result is same.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the solution i posted over here. You can do the similar way to convert GMT to your desired timezone.

[converting datetime to gmt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21745654/297113)