# How to Convert PST to GMT time in php?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I would like convert PST to GMT.

Ex:

**PST : 22:00 need to convert in to GMT. I have to consider about DAY LIGHT SAVING TIME month also.**

How can i do that?

Comment: Please try to do it yourself first: http://php.net/datetime If you fail - return here with something you've tried

Comment: If you have to consider daylight saving time, then you're talking about Pacific Time (both PST and PDT), not PST. The "S" of PST is Standard Time; it doesn't have daylight saving time.

Comment: In particular, look at the examples [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)

Answer (score 7):

### Use PHP's built-in DateTime class...

Use `DateTime` objects which have this functionality built in:

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-08-06 15:00:00', new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
echo "The time in Los Angeles is " . $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "<br>";
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
echo "The time in London is " . $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "<br>";
```

([Example Code](https://eval.in/40859)) ([Full Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php))

Answer (score 0):

I have to do similar for one my work and here it is how approached this:

```
     //date time in PST
        $t = 'Tue Feb 04 23:02:09 PST 2014';
        $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("D M d H:i:s \P\S\T Y", $t, (new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles')));
        var_dump($dateTime); // date time in PST format
        $dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
        var_dump($dateTime); // date time in GMT format
```